# Multiple CC/CV charge controllers in parallel?

Tags: lithium-ion, constant-current, charge, bms

**Can multiple cc/cv charge controllers (TS1052 for example, which is rated for 100mA drain current) in parallel configuration to achieve a higher drain current?** (input signals also connected in parallel) Or would this configuration create issues? (taking the TS1052 as an example, would putting ten of them in parallel result in ten times the max drain current? So 1000mA instead of 100mA in this example?)

Here is the datasheet for the TSM1052: https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00152575-1796500.pdf

Comment: Sorry, recommendations for specific products are off-topic on this site.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson thank you for the info. I edited my question accordingly

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood the purpose of this controller IC.

This is just the sensor to an opto coupled LED input to a flyback primary driver that can draw up to 100mA while the flyback supply charges the battery. So you can charge at any current you want and when the LED turns on, the driver is cutoff.  Choose Isense according to limit.

However there is no cutoff after CV drops below 5% to 10% of CC level which is necessary for Lithium batteries.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the circuit.
There are some that are easy to configure as such, like the LM317.
In fact they include several examples in the datasheet on doing exactly that.

[image]

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf

I took the above example, and applied it to the constant current configuration to create a 4.5A constant current source with this part.